# Is there a way to find an interface implementation based on a generic type argument?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface

I have a data access library that has a few classes that all implement the same interface, which has a generic type parameter:

```
public interface IGetByCommonStringRepository<TEntity>
{
    TEntity GetByCommonStringColumn(string commonString);
}

public class Repository1<Entity1> : IGetByCommonStringRepository<Entity1>
{
    public Entity1 GetByCommonStringColumn(string commonString)
    {
        //do stuff to get the entity
    }
}

public class Repository2<Entity2> : IGetByCommonStringRepository<Entity2>
//...and so on
```

Rather than forcing consumers of this library to instantiate one of the four repository classes separately for each `<TEntity>`, I am hoping that there's some way that I can create a static method in a "helper/utility" class in the same assembly that will be able to discern which implementation to instantiate, create an instance, and execute the `GetByCommonStringColumn` method.  Something like...

```
public static TEntity GetEntityByCommonStringColumn(string commonString) where TEntity : class
{
    IGetByCommonStringRepository<TEntity> repository = 
        DoMagicalReflectionToFindClassImplementingIGetByCommonString(typeof(TEntity));
    //I know that there would have to an Activator.CreateInstance() 
    //or something here as well.
    return repository.GetByCommonStringColumn(commonString) as TEntity;
}
```

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: The classes in your example code don't implement `IGetByCommonStringRepository<>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example still needs further fixing.. For each repository it is missing a constraint. For each public (right now it is invalid private) method it is also missing a functional body..  For that interface method it requires a generic argument.

Then try, or play around, if I understood you right:

```
public static TEntity clr_bloat_reflected_msdn_method<TEntity>(string commonString) where TEntity : class
        {
            Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            foreach (Type t in a.GetTypes())
                if (!t.IsAbstract && typeof(IGetByCommonStringRepository<TEntity>).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                    return ((IGetByCommonStringRepository<TEntity>)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).GetByCommonStringColumn(commonString);
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Edited original post to fix code.  Sometimes it's hard to translate from specific situational code in an IDE to Markdown.

Comment: First it was interrupts, then my keyboard went, then Windows started the usual 7 day running hang and losing icons, audio etc, then it went into spelling. Now it's my code-formatting on stackoverflow.com @ ASP.NET MVC. Time to go and do serious work and lose yet another addiction.. sigh.